# How do I sleep the JUnit test in Vaadin with a background thread running?

Tags: java, vaadin, junit5, vaadin-flow

Specifically I'm using JUnit 5 with Vaadin Flow (version 24) and when I click on a button it fires off a thread that can take a while for the screen to be updated. I then use:

```
UI.getCurrent().access(() -> {
    someComponent.setValue(doneStatus);
});
```

to update the UI when the thread is completed. With Junit I'm trying to do something along the lines of (ignoring any exception handling) in my JUnit test code:

```
while(checkIfDoneStatus(view.someComponent.getValue())) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

The problem is that doing this causes the Vaadin thread to sleep meaning the code in `UI.getCurrent().access() { ... };` is never run because it's always sleeping that code and not the JUnit test code.

How do I get my test code to sleep while waiting for Vaadin to be done it's work?

Comment: https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility Can help you to write asynchronous testing code.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you're using the wrong testing methodology here. Unit tests are not integration tests, and it sounds like you're testing some integration that takes time to execute. Suitable integration testing tools like Selenium or Vaadin TestBench have built-in mechanisms for waiting that would be a natural fit for a case like this.

Comment: @Knobie awaitility had the same issue sadly.

Comment: @ollitietavainen I'm actually using TestBench (for some reason I thought I was using JUnit only - sometimes you forget the obvious when you've been looking at a problem too long). Specifically vaadin-testbench-unit-junit5. That being said I don't see anything to wait for a component in Testbench. I'm going to assume I'm just not seeing something that is available.

Comment: @ollitietavainen I've gone through the Vaadin documentation again and there only seems to be 4 pages https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/testing/ui-unit with nothing about waiting. I suspect I have to be missing something or that it's not in the documentation. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The TestBench product includes browser testing (Selenium-based) and serverless UI Unit Testing. Sounds like you're using the latter while you should be using the former.